# Best way to create validation / test set when time is a factor?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

When it comes to data that has a temporal component to it, the "gold" standard in terms of validation and hyper-parameter tuning would be to use a sliding window approach. In other words, use a sliding window of size N points to evaluate the next K points after that.

However, this approach is not practical if model training is prohibitively expensive. For example, training an XGBoost model on a Spark cluster on terabytes of data over and over again.

So then what is the best approach for creating a validation set in this scenario? Let's assume we have 1 year of training data. And two months of test data after that.

1. Split the test set randomly to create a validation set and test set.
2. Split the test set by time (1 month each) to create a validation set and test set.

Option 1 intuitively feels "closer" to what we're supposed to do (test and validation set being from the same distribution), but feels more prone to over-fitting. Although is it really overfitting if the datasets are technically distinct?

Option 2 is definitely less prone to over-fitting, but will definitely produce an under-estimate of real model performance and can potentially miss important information from the time window in the test set. Also, seems like it'd be difficult to assess whether we've actually overfit or if the performance drop-off from validation to test set is simply due to the data being further out in time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

#1: Split the test set randomly to create a validation set and test set.
No, You cannnot do it. It will lead to leakage from Validation set to training set if random validation data is after the random test data. It happens all the time.

#Split the test set by time (1 month each) to create a validation set and test set.
Yes, you can do it given you are making sure that 1 month of Test data is after the 1 month of validation data.

In short,

No matter how you select the data, following constrains have to enforced:

- Training data has to be before Valid and Test data with zero temporal overlap.
- Validation data has to be before test data with zero temporal overlap.